# Are there any downsides of forcing static functions to be inline?

Tags: c, inline

Would it be good practice to declare any static, non recursive function as `inline` in an enviroment where is enough HD-space to store the binarys?

Or are there anyway cases I shouldn't forget consideringbefore I'm declaring a function as `inline`?

Comment: It also requires more memory at run-tume.

Comment: @user4098326: why? will automatic variables be in the scope of the calling scope in that case or how does it come?

Comment: If you declare all the functions as inline, you are leaving the decision  on compiler. I'd prefer to declare as inline those functions which are time critical and invoked many many times.

Comment: @Zaibis Because CPU can only execute instructions in memory.

Comment: @Marian: In this case I'm assuming the whole application is time critical. and no, I'm talking about the inline präfix (which doesn't excist on windows machine afaik) which doesn't let the compiler decide. It, as said, >forces< the compiler to treat it so.

Comment: @user4098326: I don't see the difference. function calls get executed too, even get additional stack space. So non inline code belongs into memory too, doesn't it? So in how far does this make a difference?

Comment: Like with most things it is a tradeoff. Inline functions save on the overhead of making a function call. However, it increases the total text size because every call of that function is copied "inline". That's why it can take more memory. And at a lower level, it is more likely to to cause instruction cache misses.

Comment: @AlanAu: Ah, that is going in the direction I was looking for information. sounds plausible.

Comment: I think that the `inline` keyword is just a suggestion to the compiler indicating that the coder prefers to inline given function. If there is no inline keyword, compiler can (and will) inline some static functions of his choice anyway. If you place `inline` everywhere, compiler will not inline all functions, because the code may grow too much. So, he will take decision which one to inline himself (as previously). So, this will not improve your code.

Comment: @Marian: google for `__attribute__((always_inline))` on gcc and clang base or `__inline` MSVC based. Then you probabbly better understand what I'm asking about. (because these options FORCE the compiler to take my advice, and thats what I'm talking about)

Comment: No, it's not good practice. You might be nudging the compiler into inlining stuff it otherwise would not have, which can slow down your program. Not inlining functions isn't about saving disk space. Large functions are cache-unfriendly and complicate code generation. The best advice is probably to _never_ use `inline` unless you have good reason. The compiler will then decide when to inline purely on its own. With link-time optimization, it can even inline across translation units without needing to use messy tricks with code in header files.

Comment: @Marian: Declaring a function as `inline` doesn't really have anything to do with "leaving the decision to the compiler". The compiler will inline where it thinks it's worthwhile without using `inline`, and you don't risk nudging it into making poor decisions either.

Comment: well, I assumed its clear I'm not talking about large functions (my fault, as it is NOT clear, sorry for that)

Comment: @AlanAu: could you rephrase that in any way (with additional explanations would be great) in to a answer? Because your comment is currently serving as an answer to my intentions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using -finline-functions (gcc), or just enable optimization (clang). This will effectively add "inline" before any function eligible for inlining without cluttering the code.

Inlining is merely a part of low-level optimization in modern compilers, and "inline" keyword is rarely a good way to control it.